# Знаки препинания.

Tags: пунктуация

**Плата за воду выросла. Для тех, у кого нет счетчика, - на целых 75%**
Постановку тире, если я не ошибаюсь, можно обосновать пропуском глагола?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. *Для тех, у кого нет счетчика, (плата за воду выросла) на целых 75%* Кроме того, тире возможно в стилистических целях для акцентирования - *на целых 75%*